# Subdomain webapi (asp.net mvc) responds on direct requests, but not from requests at the same domain

Tags: asp.net-web-api

- WebSite : domain.com
- Api : api.domain.com

If I make a direct request to localhost api, it works correctly.
If I make a direct request to hosted api, it works correctly.
But if I make a request from a web site on the same domain, **it does not work**.

When I make a request from web site to another hosted domain with the same api, it also works.
I also tried from a website with a javascript request. First I didn't work, but after adding `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />`, it does work.

It is clear that the problem is related to the subdomain. How can I do a same domain website request to get a response from the controller? It looks like it has to do with routing..

Thanks

Comment: Did you set CORS setting on your API to specify which domains you are allowing? If yes please share some code how you did it on C# side.

Comment: When you do the request, can you see any errors related to the request in the browser console? This will usually give some hints to what's wrong. Most likely it is a CORS issue indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for advices..

I try to set CORS settings. I follow this doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

I forget to say my first post. Website (https://domain.com.tr) works on https but api (http://api.domain.com.tr) works on http

These steps are applied

1. `config.EnableCors();` added webapi project
2. `[EnableCors(origins: "https://domain.com.tr", headers: "*", methods: "*")]` added top of the ValuesController : ApiController in webapi project

Then i make a request from other project https://domain.com.tr but it fails again which is my code below

```
        /***NOT WORK***/  
        string apiUrl = "http://api.domain.com.tr/api/";
        /***WORK PROPERLY***/  
        //string apiUrl = "http://otherdomain.com/api/";
        /***WORK PROPERLY***/  
        //string apiUrl = "http://localhost:57232/api/";

        IEnumerable<Modul> students = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
            //HTTP GET
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync("GetPages");
            responseTask.Wait();
            /***AFTER THİS LINE GIVE ERROR***/
            var result = responseTask.Result;
```

enter image description here